# If $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y+z=0$, is it true that $x^4+y^4+z^4=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: functions, polynomials, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials, constraints

Suppose $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y+z=0$.

Is it then true that $x^4+y^4+z^4=\frac{1}{2}$?

I have a hunch that it's true (all the numbers I've tried have confirmed this) - but I don't know how to show this.

My thought was to write $x = - y - z$, and then plug that into the other expression so that $(-y-z)^2+y^2+z^2=1$, but this doesn't help me out here.

Comment: That should help some.  You have $(y+z)^2+y^2+z^2=2 (yz+y^2+z^2) =1$ which should allow you to find to solutions to z in terms of y.  Test them both out and it seems reasonable they will yield the result.  Probably.  I haven'haven't done it but it seems very plausible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^4+y^4+z^4=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2-2(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)=1-2(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)$$

Now $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2=(xy+yz+zx)^2-2xyz(x+y+z)=(xy+yz+zx)^2-0$

Again, $2(xy+yz+zx)=(x+y+z)^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0-1$

Answer (score 3):

We have $2(xy+yz+zx)=(x+y+z)^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0-1$

So, $x,y,z$ are the roots of $t^3-\dfrac t2-c=0$ where $c=xyz$

$\implies t^4-\dfrac{t^2}2-ct=0$

Put $t=x,y,z$ and add to find $x^4+y^4+z^4=\dfrac{x^2+y^2+z^2}2+c(x+y+z)=\dfrac{x^2+y^2+z^2}2+c\cdot0$

Answer (score 2):

From the conditions we have $xy+xz+yz=\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence, $x^4+y^4+z^4=$
$$=(x+y+z)^4-4(x+y+z)^2(xy+xz+yz)+2(xy+xz+yz)^2+4(x+y+z)xyz=$$
$$=2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}$$